# Humor like we saw

Tags: definite-article, pronouns

Which are grammatical?

> a. We don't want to see humor like *we saw* in last week's program.
>
> b. We don't want to see humor like *the humor we saw* in last week's program.
>
> c. We don't want to see humor like *what we saw* in last week's program.

Which imply that we don't want any humor?

Which imply that we don't want the kind of humor we saw in last week's program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are all grammatical.

As I read them, none of these sentences imply that we don't want *any* humor. They all imply that we don't want the kind of humor that we saw last week.

However, a) and c) are ambiguous; I think a native speaker could interpret a) and c) either way, and other native speakers might have a different 'first instinct' than mine. Which is not great; you want to communicate clearly, and sentences like these often create misunderstandings.

In order to imply that we don't want *any* humor, I would write this:

> We don't want to see humor, like we saw in last week's program.